# Decoding an encrypted file using Caesar Cipher

Tags: python

I want to decrypt an encrypted file.  I'm having trouble all the way at the bottom when converting it and comparing it to a dictionary (which is full of words).  Can someone guide me in the right direction?  I'm struggling comparing the two.

```
#this function takes a string and encrypts ONLY letters by k shifts
def CaeserCipher(string, k):
    #setting up variables to move through
    upper = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'*10000
    lower = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'*10000

    newCipher = ''

    #looping each letter and moving it k times
    for letter in string:
        if letter in upper:
            if upper.index(letter) + k > 25:
                indexPosition = (upper.index(letter) + k) 
                newCipher = newCipher + upper[indexPosition]
            else:
                indexPosition = upper.index(letter) + k
                newCipher = newCipher + upper[indexPosition]
        elif letter in lower:
            if lower.index(letter) + k > 25:

                indexPosition = (lower.index(letter) + k)  
                newCipher = newCipher + lower[indexPosition]
            else:
                indexPosition = lower.index(letter) + k
                newCipher = newCipher + lower[indexPosition]
        else:
            newCipher = newCipher + letter


    return newCipher

f = open('dictionary.txt', "r")
dictionary = set()
for line in f:
    word = line.strip()
    dictionary.add(word)
print dictionary

#main file
#reading file and encrypting text

f = open('encryptMystery1.txt')
string = ''
out = open("plain1.txt", "w")
myList = []
for line in f:
    myList.append(line)

for sentence in myList:
    for k in range(26):
        updatedSentence = CaeserCipher(sentence, k)
        for word in updatedSentence.split():
            if word in dictionary:
                out.write(updatedSentence)
                break
print myList
f.close()
out.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's tackle this in steps, and the first step is entitled

#### WHY DO YOU HAVE 260,000 CHARACTER LONG STRINGS IN A CAESAR CIPHER

Sorry, I don't mean to be overly dramatic, but you realize that's going to take up more space than, well, ***Space***, don't you? And it's completely unnecessary. It's an ugly and slow hack to avoid understanding the `%` (modulo) operator. Don't do that.

#### Now, to the modulo:

Step two of course will have to be understanding the modulo. It's not actually hard, it's just like the remainder of a division problem. You remember when you were in school and just LEARNING division? `7/4` was `1r3` not `1.75`, remember? Well Python has functions for all that. `7/4 == 1.75`, `7//4 == 1` and `7 % 4 == 3`. This is useful because it can serve to "wrap" a number around a fixed length.

Let's say for example you have some string with 26 indexes (like, I don't know, an alphabet?). You're trying to add some number to a starting index, then return the result but UGH YOU'RE ADDING 2 TO `Y` AND IT DOESN'T WORK! Well with modulo it can. `Y` is in index 24 (remember zero is its own index), and 24+2 is 26 and there IS no 26th index. However, if you know there's going to be only 26 elements in your string, we can take the modulo and use THAT instead.

By that logic, `index + CONSTANT % len(alphabet)` will ALWAYS return the right number using simple math and not sweet baby jesus the quarter million element long string you just butchered.

Ugh your mother would be ashamed.

#### Reversing a Caesar cipher

So you've got a good idea, going through each line in turn and applying every kind of cipher to it. If I were you I'd dump them all into separate files, or even into separate list elements. Remember though that if you're reversing the cipher, you need to use `-k` not `k`. It's probably a good idea to simply change your Caesar cipher to detect that though, since the modulo trick doesn't work in this case. Try something like:

```
def cipher(text, k):
    cipherkey = "SOMESTRINGGOESHERE"
    if k < 0:
        k = len(cipherkey) + k
        # len(cipherkey) - abs(k) would be more clear, but if it HAS to be
        # a negative number to get in here, it seems silly to add the call
        # to abs
```

Then you can do:

```
startingtext = "Encrypted_text_goes_here"
possibledecrypts = [cipher(startingtext, -i) for i in range(1,26)]
```

Comment: Can you smooth your language out a little? Borderline abusive.

Comment: @2rs2ts I'd just as soon leave it for effect. If you're concerned about it you can certainly propose an edit and leave it for review, I won't veto :)

Comment: I have no interest in rewriting your prose, but you do realize my point, yeah?

Comment: @2rs2ts I realize the point you're making, but I don't agree, that's all. This isn't a classroom, and this isn't the first time I've answered this question from this user (check his question history). When I saw his `"abc...z"*10000` I was truly shocked :)

Comment: @2rs2ts You could also flag it for moderator attention. I certainly am not against the language changing for any reason other than the drop in impact level.